# Why is my DEM not caching correctly?

Tags: arcgis-server, tilecache, cache

Relating to a previous [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13809/where-can-i-get-australian-spatial-data), found an excellent source for data called [Koordinates](http://koordinates.com).

I downloaded t[his 5m DEM of New Zealand](http://koordinates.com/#/layer/2137-wellington-city-5m-digital-elevation-model-2004/), Wellington.
This is in a TIFF format and I have added to ArcMap 10, applied a colour ramp, some hillshading, and applied a standard deviation on the histogram:

[image]

I know that the MSD format does not support hillshading, so I published direct from the MXD.  As a dynamic service, it draws fine (but slow as you would expect).

So I cached the service using Mixed mode, and the compact storage type.

Viewing the cache in both ArcGIS Desktop and REST, the resulting cache is a solid red:
[image]

At some of the closer levels, the expected symbolgy comes through in some tiles:
[image]

Have tried re-creating several times and still getting the same problem.

**Would like some advice on troubleshooting this.**
Have not seen anything related in the Esri forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue seems to be specific to compact caches and works fine with exploded caches.
Ill follow up with Esri Support.  But for now, consider this answered.

Comment: Try building statistics on the raster

Comment: If you have the answer you were looking for, please mark it as the accepted answer... even if it's your own answer. In fact, I think you'll get a badge on your profile for it :)

Comment: Will hold off doing that until I get a better answer (i.e. more info from Esri)

Comment: What often works in arcgis is using the raster calculator and calculating a new grid with exactly the same values as the old one. Often raster problems are gone when using the new grid. I suppose it recalculates some statistics and caches.