# Looking for Melbourne and Canberra metropolitan suburb shapefiles / ABS coded lists

Tags: data, australia

I am looking for shapefiles or a list of suburb names for Melbourne and Canberra.
I have ABS shapefiles, but I need to filter that to end up with only metropolitan suburbs.

My shapefile has codes in it for [Census Geographical Area Classification Listing](http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@.nsf/66f306f503e529a5ca25697e0017661f/99FE76C6D6BE36A4CA256C2500036F77?opendocument) - I just need to know which suburbs belong to the metros.

Comment: See if this post helps or not: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13809/where-can-i-get-australian-spatial-data

Comment: http://www.data.vic.gov.au

Comment: Do you want the suburbs to be matched specifically to the Metropolitan areas or are Regional areas enough?

Comment: In Queensland suburb boundaries are stored in datasets named Localities but I do not know if that is the same in Victoria and the ACT. It is perhaps another keyword that you can use for searching.

Comment: You appear to be linking to a very ancient set of boundaries - these are more current for ABS purposes (http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1270.0.55.003July%202011). Note - these are all aligned at the Meshblock level - so will nest into LGA definitions. Depending on how you're defining metropolitan, then you could just group the Melbourne and Canberra LGAs on that definition and then select out all the suburbs within the grouped LGAs?

Comment: I finally received the dataset to mapped against my suburbs and this makes my job plenty easier. I join the tables and use the suburbs where I have data and - in case of white spots - any suburb that is within the range of the outermost suburbs with data.

This may not be the ultimate independent solution, but works perfectly in my situation.

Answer (score 2):

For Melbourne Australia

https://mapzen.com/metro-extracts/

has OpenStreetMap Data for Melbourne in Shapefile format.

Answer (score 2):

Canberra Suburbs aren't like suburbs in the rest of Australia. In fact, the link you posted doesn't even list Canberra suburbs. However, there aren't many and it shouldn't be too hard to identify which ones are metropolitan. They may all be considered metropolitan.  Have a look at the Wikipedia page of the **[list of Canberra Suburbs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Canberra_suburbs)**.

However, if you go to **[this page](http://www.abs.gov.au/ausstats/abs@.nsf/66f306f503e529a5ca25697e0017661f/675D81318A053819CA256C2500036F6E?opendocument)**, you'll see that Melbourne and Surrounds are in the range **21006–22726**.  That's as close to "metropolitan" that you'll get.  I haven't seen any other dataset which identifies metropolitan vs regional.

Comment: Thanks, this sounds like a viable path go down. I will (probably be monday at this stage) pursue this and report back. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

This will not answer your question, infact you will probably have much better data, but I've posted it incase it might be of some use. You can download the administrative-areas shapefile for the whole of Australia from here: http://www.diva-gis.org/gdata

You receive 3 shapefiles of varying levels, probably the most suitable one is shown below:

[image: Administrative areas for Australia]

You will see from its attributes the different suburbs but I believe these are for Regional areas rather than Metropolitan areas, hence it may be difficult to differentiate between them (apologies for not knowing the correct term, I blame that for not being an Aussie!)

[image: Attribute table]

Comment: Thank you - indeed, this is accurate data, however my challenge is to get the metro suburbs filtered out of it and there's no explicit column to do it by.